# Can not see a Value in another class ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

My project have a structure like

- Project_ASP

  - Customer(folder)
  - Info.aspx
- Login.aspx

**Login.aspx**

```
//oracle_connection'
pasrsing data from Oracle
private string ResultPassport = string.Empty;

public string PassportResult
{
    get
    {
        return ResultPassport;
    }
    set
    {
        ResultPassport = value;
    }
}
```

```
Login obj = new Login();
obj.PassportResult = dr.GetString(0);
```

Info.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Login obj = new Login();
     TextBox3.Text = obj.PassportResult;      
 }
```

The problem is, that I can not see the result in Info.aspx

Where my mistake?

Comment: You don't show the `Login` constructor, so we can't help to fix that code. But in general, two pages don't exist beneath each other, only one. A page and all of its objects(including controls) will be disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle when the rendered HTML was sent to the client.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I do not have any constructor in Login.aspx. I get all needed data in Login.aspx, but one string of data I want to send to Info.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect to?

You're creating a new `Login` object:

```
Login obj = new Login();
```

Then you access a property on that new object:

```
obj.PassportResult
```

What is that property?:

```
private string ResultPassport = string.Empty;
public string PassportResult
{
    get
    {
        return ResultPassport;
    }
    set
    {
        ResultPassport = value;
    }
}
```

The value is, by default, `string.Empty`.  So you're getting `string.Empty`, as expected.

(Side note: The naming of that property and backing variable is just *begging* for a `StackOverflowException` one of these days.  You might want to choose more clear names to distinguish the property from the variable.)

You did set a value on a *previous* object:

```
Login obj = new Login();
obj.PassportResult = dr.GetString(0);
```

But that wasn't the same object.  If you want to get the value from that object then you need to access *that object*.  Unless the value is `static` (which *probably* isn't what you want to do in a web application), you need to maintain a reference to that same instance or persist and retrieve it somewhere.

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  This is simply how C# (and any language, really) works.  Setting values on one object doesn't affect other objects.

There are a number of options for passing along the state of that object from one page to another.  Probably the most straightforward for what you're doing here is to use session state.  Something like this:

```
Login obj = new Login();
obj.PassportResult = dr.GetString(0);
Session["PassportResult"] = obj;
```

Then in the later page:

```
Login obj = (Login)Session["PassportResult"];
```

This has a few drawbacks, particularly when it comes to scalability.  You'll also want to do some error checking to make sure the object is there before trying to retrieve and cast it, of course.  But in most cases this should get the job done.

What's *really* confusing here is why you're creating instances of `Page` objects and setting values on them.  If you step back a minute and describe the nature of what it is you're actually trying to accomplish here, there's likely a much simpler way to do it.  For example, passing the value along on the URL or in a form element would be very simple and would scale much more effectively, if it's just that one string value.  (Though the drawback there is that the user would be able to edit it, so that may be a concern.)

Comment: I got   "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type"
 Login obj2 = (Login)Session["PassportResult"]; on Info.aspx

Comment: @Kapi1256: What did you store in the session object?  Was it a `Login` object or a `String` object?  If you're just looking to transfer this one value then perhaps you should skip using the `Login` object entirely and just store/retrieve only that string value from Session anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Things doesnt work like that. First of all, in your Info.aspx, you create another object Login, wich means, it is a new one in your Heap memory, and your fields are empty. To pass information between pages, you can use:

- Session (Bad Practice)
- Cookies
- Querystring
- Get from database

Or you can use `PreviousPage` property, like this:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
{
    TextBox SourceTextBox = 
        (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
    if (SourceTextBox != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PreviousPage` approach works only if `Login` was actually the previous page and also if [`Server.Transfer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9e2zxx(v=vs.110).aspx) was used to redirect to this page.